# How %g works in printf

Tags: c

The `%g` description says

> Use the shortest representation: `%e` or `%f`

for example,
`544666.678` is written as `544667` if `%.6g` is used which is fine.

But the same number is written as `5.4467E+5` when `%.5g` is used.

Why would it use exponential notation (`%e`) here while `544670` (`%f`) is shorter in length than that.

Can anyone please help me to understand? Is this a bug?

Similarly, `44.35` is written as `44.4` when `%.1f` is used which is fine.
but `44.55` is written as `44.5` when `%.1f` is used. Why isn't it written as `44.6`? Is this a bug?

Comment: Binary can't represent decimal fractions exactly.  The chances are that 44.55 is just fractionally smaller than the half-way point and is therefore rounded down, while 44.35 is just fractionally bigger and is rounded up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Use the shortest representation: %e or %f* is not precise enough.

> #### C11 7.21.6.1 The `fprintf` function
>
> A `double` argument representing a floating-point number is converted in style `f` or `e` (or in style `F` or `E` in the case of a `G` conversion specifier), depending on the value converted and the precision. Let `P` equal the precision if nonzero, `6` if the precision is omitted, or `1` if the precision is zero. Then, if a conversion with style E would have an exponent of `X` :
>
> — if `P > X ≥ −4`, the conversion is with style `f` (or `F`) and precision `P − (X + 1)`.
>
> — otherwise, the conversion is with style `e` (or `E`) and precision `P − 1`.
>
> Finally, unless the `#` flag is used, any trailing zeros are removed from the fractional portion of the result and the decimal-point character is removed if there is no fractional portion remaining.

So in the example of `%.5g` with `544666.678`, `P` is `5`, and `X` being `5`, according to the rule, the style `e` is used because `P > X ≥ −4` is false.

Comment: Using the "f" form here would misrepresent the output as having 6 significant digits when in fact it only has 5. That's the motivation for the behavior and should probably be mentioned.