# Replacing printf("%g", value) with a stream manipulation

Tags: c++, iostream

I wanted to replace an implementation of:

```
float value = 3.14;
printf("%g", value);
```

(See [How %g works in printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669026/how-g-works-in-printf) for the explanation of `%g` if required).

But I haven't found an equivalent in the stream manipulators, only for either fixed or scientific, but not the shortest of both (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed). Does this exist or is there a "simple" way to implement this?

Some examples from the linked SO question:

- 544666.678 is written as 544667 if `%.6g` is used,
- The same number is written as 5.4467E+5 when `%.5g` is used.

Comment: can you give some example of inputs and expected output so that we don't have to dive in you link? tanx

Comment: @OznOg Goog point, I integrated the examples from the C question, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%g` is the default behavior. For example:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::setprecision(6) << 544666.678 << "\n"
              << std::setprecision(5) << 544666.678 << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
544667
5.4467e+05
```

The default behavior can be retained with the manipulator `std::defaultfloat` after `std::fixed` or `std::scientific` is set.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xe4E7ua3St6ghWHS)

Comment: Nice, defnitely +1! Though I kind of disagree with your initial wording "you can easily implement such a manipulator". But that might just be my cognitive limitations^^

Comment: @lubgr Well, indeed. I have reworded.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Damn ... I just realized I was reimplementing the default behavior ...

Comment: Oh... Good to know then :D